# Migrate password Symfony2 to CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, symfony, encryption, sha1, salt

I am migrating a project in Symfony to CodeIgniter. I have a problem with password user: I don't know how to create the same password in Codeigniter.

Example with the password is : `aze`. In the database, I have:

Password : `284261c499a22c0de073b642f2d55b0684c86555`
Salt : `iudcjri8lnkgosgo0k00skwo8cwssgc`

Symfony security config:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Kalisteco\AdminSpaceBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

I tried with this code:

```
$password = "aze"
$salt = "iudcjri8lnkgosgo0k00skwo8cwssgc";
$str = do_hash($str.$salt, 'sha1'); // Result : f767fd2c23e045f24e8dc065814dea4242591642
$str = do_hash($salt.$str, 'sha1'); // Result : de47f71660f92fbfc583b4dd779f28c35c38e785
```

Comment: Are you going from CodeIgniter to Symfony2, or the other way around?

Comment: Hi Hafler, for the other way around.
I'm sorry for my english

Comment: No worries, made a small edit for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony surrounds the salt with `{` and `}`:

```php
$salted = $password.'{'.$salt.'}';
```

Comment: Yes it's ok with {} ! Thank you very much !